# Наследование методов перегрузки операторов

Tags: python

В каждом классе имеется свой набор перегруженных операторов по умолчанию. Тогда почему если я определю свой метод перегрузки в классе в дереве выше, то в наследующем классе будет использоваться метод перегрузки определенный мной, хотя он и так имеется в своем же классе по умолчанию?

Comment: Потому что ищет методы по названию снизу вверх по дереву. Так и задуманно.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что в классе a2 есть метод `__repr__`? Вы же его там не определили. Дефолтная реализация `__repr__` не добавляется в каждый класс, она лежит в классе `Object`. Если в текущем классе нет нужного метода, Python начинает искать такой метод в классах-предках в порядке наследования. В вашем случае он находит метод `__repr__` класса a1 раньше, чем метод класса `Object`, поэтому вызывает его.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы использовать предопределённый метод в классе предке его необходимо вызвать в потомке явно, например:

## код

```
def __add__(self, val=None):
    predok.__add__(self, val)
```